# How to use RE's to find strings that appear after certain text?

Tags: python, regex

I have a number of large files that contain some strings I need to extract. The data is set out as follows:

```
"text":"string","token":"1357580140-7","display_token":0,"display_ttl":1357828250,"coeff2_ts":"2013-01-08","timestamp":1357845041}}
```

I have done some research and decided that RE's would be best. I only need to print out the "string" not the "text": bit. The desired output would be just the "string"

```
def regEx():
os.chdir("C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/FilesWithString")
files = os.listdir(".")
for x in files:
    re.search(r'(?<="text":)("[^"]+")',x).group(0)
```

Comment: How is your rest of the file's content ordered? What do they look like?

Comment: You need to provide us with some more sample input and what output you expect. It sounds as if you can solve this without regular expressions just fine.

Comment: I really think this kind of task should be completed without using regexp.

Comment: I have updated the question with more of the file, cant put it all because its a large file and have tried to explain the output more

Comment: You are looking at JSON data, I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lookbehind:

```
your_string = '"text":"string"'
match = re.search(r'(?<=:)("[^"]+")',your_string)
if match:
    print match.group(0) #'"string"'
```

This captures anything bracketed in double quotes immediately following a `:`.

As a side note, with your updated string, it looks an awful lot like `JSON` -- or something that `ast.literal_eval` could handle.  If that's the case, you could use either of those to evaluate it into a dictionary which you could just subscript to get the string.

Comment: this sounds kind of like what i need but wouldn't work because that would return more than I need. I need the string that appears only after '"text":I have put more of the input file in the question.

Comment: @LWH91 -- Then just include that in the lookahead:  `r'(?<="text":)("[^"]+")'`

Comment: if I was running this inside a for loop would I replace "your_string" with the variable I put in the for loop? and how do I print out the "string"?

Comment: how do i make it print out the string that appears after "text":?

Comment: @LWH91 -- That's what the `.group(0)` returns.

Comment: I get an attribute error when I run it, it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

Comment: @LWH91 -- that's because you have a string where no match was found.

Comment: I've put the code im trying to use in the question now. Can you check if it is right please. I know there is a file in the directory that contains "text":.

Comment: @LWH91 -- You're not reading any of the files.  You're checking the regex against the filenames, not the file contents.  Additionally, usually you do the regex searching and group extraction in 2 steps.  I'll edit to demonstrate.

Comment: if the input file has multiple matches how would I make the code print out all matches? at the moment it only prints out the first match

Comment: @LWH91 -- you could try `re.findall` instead of `re.search`.  `findall` will give you a list of all non-overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON string, just use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to decode it to a Python structure:

```
import json

data = json.loads(inputstring)

print data['somekey']['token']
print data['somekey']['display_ttl']
```

Comment: the text I need to print out appears more than once, would what youve put above print out all the strings that appear after "text":  ?

Comment: @LWH91: There is probably a *nested* structure; dictionaries inside of dictionaries. Since you didn't post the whole sample, I don't know what the structure looks like in it's entirety. Your sample *does* end in a double curly brace, which suggests there is a parent dict with dicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much faster without re:

```
s = '"text":"string"'
print s[7:]
>>> "string"
```

in case the `text` part varies along different lines you can measure its length - by splitting the line on the colon and taking the first part:

```
s = '"a text":"a string"'
s[len(s.split('":')[0]) + 2:]
>>> '"a string"'
```

Or even more efficiently, use `index` function:

```
s = '"a text":"a string"'
s[s.index('":') + 2:]
>>> '"a string"'
```

Comment: The slicing solution is far too limited to be of much use I would think.  But the `str.split` solution shows some promise.